# ChromeDriver Eating Disk Space

Tags: vb.net, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not sure what is going on, but every time I run my application (vb.net) Chromedriver eats disk space.  I even added another 40GB (Virtual Machine) and now that is gone!

I'm doing the typical:

```
Dim driver as ChromeDriver = New Chromedriver
driver.Navigate.GoToUrl.....
```

both on form load, essentially.  I constantly re-work the code, so I exit out and have to manually close the console window, maybe that is causing the issue.  Will have to put some ChromeDriver destroying instead of letting garbage collection manage that.

HOWEVER: 
Where are these files so that I can delete them?

Comment: Something like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) should make it easy to find where that amount of disk space is being used.

Comment: I think it doesn't help when it is likely putting very small files into a directory because I still can't find where the disk space is being eaten up and I've used WinDirStat and  WizTree to try to figure it out. :(

Comment: In that case, you could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see where the files are going. (You might need to devise a suitable filter to catch only what you want to see.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the files are folders named `scoped_dir*` inside `C://Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp`. You can type `%APPDATA%` in the search window on your taskbar to go to `AppData` folder and then remove those `scoped` folders.